# How do I break the tyranny of the clientID?

Tags: jsf-2

My least favorite part of coding JSF 2.0 forms has to do with the handing of the **id** attributes of the various input elements.  I am forever having trouble coding the clientID of the target component from within the backing bean, particularly since PrimeFaces **tabView** now includes the id of the **p:tab** element as part of the clientID.   I waste tons of time coding, testing, then re-coding those clientIDs.

It is reminiscent of older-style assembly language programming where you have to generate tons of label names for your branches and loops.  I've done of enough of that for a lifetime.

One approach I am trying is to use only auto-generated **id** attributes.  For example one line of my form might look like this.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Full Name:" />
<p:inputText value="#{editUser.user.fullName}"
             binding="#{editUser.compFullName}"/>
<p:message for="#{editUser.compFullName.clientId}" />
```

Note that I do not have an explicit **id** attribute.  Then in the backing bean:

```
    String clientID = getCompFullName().getClientId();
    msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, 
            "Summary Message For Full Name", "Detail Message Full Name");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientID, msg);
```

This always works, even if the component has a complex clientID, such as when PrimeFaces inserts the **p:tab** id into the clientID.  (Which it does starting v 3).  Rearranging the form never breaks anything.

It is, however, laborious, since I have to create UIComponent properties, getters and setters, and bind them in the form with **binding** attributes.  Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: Maybe UIComponent.getCurrentComponent() or getCurrentCompositeComponent() and then use findComponent()/invokeOnComponent() over that component to find the right one? It depends on the context the expression is evaluated, but I suppose it will do the trick (but I'm not 100% sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *since I have to create UIComponent properties, getters and setters, and bind them in the form with binding attributes. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?*

It's not required to bind the component to some backing bean if you don't use it in there at all. Just bind it to the view instead:

```
<p:inputText value="#{editUser.user.fullName}"
             binding="#{compFullName}"/>
<p:message for="#{compFullName.clientId}" />
```

To make the code more self-documenting, I suggest to put a `HashMap` in the request scope by `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Holder of all component bindings.</description>
    <managed-bean-name>components</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

with

```
<p:inputText value="#{editUser.user.fullName}"
             binding="#{components.fullName}"/>
<p:message for="#{components.fullName.clientId}" />
```

Adding messages is supposed to be done by a `Converter` or a `Validator` which is trowing it as a `ConverterException` or `ValidatorException` respectively. It will automatically end up in the right message holder. Or if it are informal messages, just add it on the client ID of the `UIComponent` which is already available as method argument.

#### See also:

- [JSF component binding without bean property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168302/jsf-component-binding-without-bean-property)

Comment: These are really interesting ideas -- I'll play with them a bit.   The main reason I was binding to the backing bean is because it is there -- when I have to call the **addMessage** method -- that I have the most trouble.   The **id** <-> **for** pairing is not that bad because there you deal with element ids and not clientID.  I think what I will try next is to use your managed bean map and inject it into the managed bean that needs the clientID.  That way I don't have to create individual **UIComponent** properties and their accessor methods.

Comment: I have the impression that you're actually validating inside a backing bean action method. You should do that in a `Validator` instead. There in you can do `context.addMessage(component.getclientId(), message);` for info messages. Inside an action method, the `addMessage()` is more supposed to be done on `null` client ID only, as kind of a *global* message.

Comment: you nailed me.   I tend to do edit-checks in the action or actionListener method.  I'll re-evaluate.

Comment: @AlanObject: `components` is a request scoped managed bean, so you gonna very limit option on where you can inject. But it is a good idea. Did u play with it and find a way to get it work nicely?