# (Primefaces + JSF) error in tab ajax

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

my code:

```
<h:form id="form">
            <p:tabView dynamic="true" id="tabform" orientation="left">
                <p:tab id="tab1" title="Tree">
                    <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:panel style="float:left">
                        <p:tree value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node" dynamic="true" cache="false"  
                                selectionMode="single"  selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}" id="tree" >  
                            <p:ajax event="expand" update=":form:tabform:tab1" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}" />
```

and i have an error: http://i283.photobucket.com/albums/kk308/breakbk/Untitled-1.jpg

please explain to me why, thank for any suggestion :)

Comment: Does it work with `update=@form`?

Comment: yes, it work with update=@form :|

Comment: i don't want to update all, because form have many component.

Comment: @user1254072: Please copy and paste the error here. This way, it will still be there when the image link dies, and it can be found by the search.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem of wrong id in `p:ajax`'s update `attribute`.

Look into the rendered html source of your page and identify the correct id of the tab. Maybe you missed a sub-component in the id string.

Comment: id is ":form:tabform:tab1", as you see id flow: form->tabform->tab1

Comment: Is this really the id from the html source in browser? The trailing ":" indicates that it isn't.

Comment: html source:
<div class="ui-tabs-panels"><div id="form:tabform:tab1" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">

Comment: So the id string is correct. So, from theory it should work. What is if you update the whole tabview?

Comment: sorry. if update=":form:tabform:tab1", it work. but update=":form:tabform:tab1:messages" it report above error :|
i have many components, so i don't want to update whole tabview.

Comment: update=":form:tabform:tab1:messages", it report error(in picture) in my question :|

Comment: Are you sure this exception isn't thrown from your event listener method. Is this the whole stack trace?

Comment: no, it very long, i can not display all. think i must use update=":form:tabform:tab1" :|

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution

you can bind the element that you want to render to a hashmap that will exist in request scope

and than use that binding in the `render` attribute , it might sound complicated , but its not

here an example

put a HashMap in the request scope by faces-config.xml:

```
<managed-bean>
    <description>Holder of all component bindings.</description>
    <managed-bean-name>components</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.HashMap</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

than use it like this:

```
<p:message binding="#{components.myMessage}"></p:message>
```

or

```
 <p:tab binding="#{components.myTabName}"></p:tab>
```

and finally render it like this

```
<p:ajax event="expand" update="#{components.myMessage.clientId}" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}"></p:ajax>
```

or

```
<p:ajax event="expand" update="#{components.myTabName.clientId}" listener="#{treeBean.onNodeExpand}"></p:ajax>
```

This solution was taken from BalusC older answers on how to get the id [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340408/617373)...